# namespace methods

Tags: javascript, object, scope, prototype

I want to namespace an object of mine. That means I want to call a specific method instead of:

```
mediator.startSandbox();
```

like this:

```
mediator.sandbox.start();
```

Basically this isn't that hard. Just wrap the sandbox methods into another object. Unfortunately this brings up one big side:

**I can't access mediator anymore through *this* when working in a function of sandbox (*this* refers to sandbox)**

This always catches me up again in development... Is there any workaround for this problem available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a var as such:

```
var med = this;
```

In the object mediator and use `med` inside the object sandbox.

Comment: Is this practice amd compatible? So can I use this with requireJs?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a requireJS fan. I've barely used it I can not help on on that mater.